# Comparison ordering of python built-in types

Tags: python, comparison, built-in-types

I'm looking for a good set of sentinel values, e.g. experimentally:

```
[] > "sdfasfg" > ()
```

And this seems to be documented:

> CPython implementation detail: Objects of different types except
>   numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types
>   that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address. [reference](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

In the same fashion,

```
object() < str()
```

The "largest" builtin type seems to be `unicode`, what can I use as a "right" sentinel value for comparison with unicode types? That is a value that's larger than any unicode string?

Is comparison order of instances of built-in types really well defined in Python?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Like you stated in your post, it's a CPython implementation detail, and has been removed altogether in Python 3.

Comment: I'm looking for a sentinel value -- that is something that's smaller than or larger than any user object, e.g. any string/.

Comment: Yes, but why? In any case, you shouldn't rely on implementation details.

Comment: You can try to create your own class and override `__gt__`, `__lt__`, `__gte__`, `__lte__` methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparison of arbitrary objects is called "rich comarisons".  There is some documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.1.html#pep-207-rich-comparisons), and [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html).

If you are working with Python 3, then check this [out](http://python3porting.com/preparing.html).  Relevant quote from this source:

> Having both the rich comparison methods and the `__cmp__()` method violates the principle that there should be only one obvious way to do it, so in Python 3 the support for `__cmp__()` has been removed. For Python 3 you therefore must implement all of the rich comparison operators if you want your objects to be comparable.

Comment: thank for the links, very informative. do I read your answer right that I must diy, that is implement my own custom objects for sentinels?